# What is the linguistic term for 'it'

Tags: english, terminology, pronouns

'This' is proximal demonstrative pronoun/ adjective.
 'That' is distal demonstrative pronoun/ adjective. 
What is 'it' called?

Answer (score 7):

It is a neutral (as opposed to feminine "she" and masculine "he"), singular, third person personal pronoun (**not** an adjective).

Comment: and not demonstrative like _this_ and _that_. _It_ is in a different paradigm.

Comment: It is also has a nominative or accusative case (subject/object), so can contrast with *her* and *him* as well as with *she* and *he*

Comment: But what term should be used in contrast with 'distal' or 'proximal'. Does 'non-directional' qualify?

Answer (score 2):

'It' is a neutral third person singular personal pronoun. 'It' can be used as a subject or object, as opposed to the other third person pronouns:
'he' (subject) vs 'him' (object) and
'she' (subject) vs 'her' (object)